# Jquery datepicker only working on chrome (Ruby On Rails)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, datepicker

I have a form with two inputs:
The first is a datepicker and the second is a select picker with options appended to it when the user click on the datepicker.
This is working great on chrome but neither on safari and firefox.

```
<div id="datepicker" class="public-holiday-date-pick">
</div>

<select class="form-control" id="appointment_date" name="appointment[date]">
  <option value="">Veuillez chosir une date</option>
</select>
```

My jquery code is here
[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1hr1enqa/)

I can't make it work on Jsfiddle but it's working on chrome on my rails app both in environnement and production environnement (but not on safari and firefox)

I use jQuery JavaScript Library v2.2.3 and jQuery UI Datepicker 1.10.3

Thank you if you have any tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8" />
      <title>Datepicker fadein</title>
      <link  href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){
                $('.datepicker').datepicker({showAnim: "fadeIn"});
            })
     </script>.

   <body>
     <input class="datepicker">
  </body>
```

Comment: Thank you for your tip Vijay.